# Handling layout event in Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a issue with Vaadin. It seems as the layout click event listener consumes my right clicks as well as left clicks.

I have a layout with some components inside, and when I try to right click for inspecting my elements, nothing happens in the browser since the event is consumed by the code.

Is there a way to prevent it from capturing the right mouse click? Thanks! Checking what was pushed inside the event does not affect the behaviour.. My listener;

```
this.addLayoutClickListener(new LayoutEvents.LayoutClickListener() {
    public void layoutClick(LayoutEvents.LayoutClickEvent event) {
            System.out.println("clicked.."  +  getSuit());
    }});
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are adding a click listener to the entire layout, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have made a card deck which is made of playing cards. Each card has it's own layout. I want to be able to click the whole card, for example for removing it or other stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the answer is you can't. See: https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/696409/701753

Now admittedly that is an old answer, but I just tried with vaadin7 and seems to me the behaviour hasn't changed. So you are left with extending the client side if you want to change the behaviour: https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/gwt.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to inspect specific element you can do:

In Google Chrome:

- open  Developer Tools (F12),
- click on button "Select an element in the page to inspect it." (Magnifier icon on top left),
- inspect your element.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! However what I want is to be able to right click my element and inspect (when having a clicklistener on the layout).